# cannot access protected route with passport-jwt

Tags: express, jwt, postman, unauthorized, passport-jwt

I'm not able to authenticate the secret resource, I'm calling with login token still I'm getting unauthorized in response every time.

```
  passport.use(
  new JwtStrategy(
    {
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromHeader("Authorization"),
      secretOrKey: jwtSecret
    },
    async (payload, done) => {
      try {
        const user = await User.findById(payload.sub);
        console.log(payload.sub);
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false);
        }
        done(null, user);
      } catch (error) {
        done(error, false);
      }
    }
  )
);
```

controllers/users.js :

```
const signToken = user => {
  return jwt.sign(
    {
      iss: "nikname",
      iat: new Date().getTime(),
      sub: user._id,
      exp: new Date().setTime(new Date().getDate() + 1)
    },
    jwtSecret
  );
};
```

route :

```
router.route('/secret')
.get(passport.authenticate('jwt',{session: false}),usersController.secret);
```

I'm not able to figure out the problem since the error is unclear.
any help ? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: I tried out with other exctractors : fromAuthHeaderasBearerToken(), fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("jwt"), without sucess

Comment: console.log(payload.sub) does not show anything its is like it does not read jwtStrategy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after using the jwt debugger , it appeared that there was an issue with payload , although the debugger showed a verified token sign, but the 'exp' and 'iat' showed wrong dates, so I changed the signToken constant like this :

```
    const signToken = user => {
  return jwt.sign(
    {
      iss: "nikname",
      sub: user.id,
    },
    jwtSecret,
    {
      expiresIn: '2d'
    }
  );
};
```

also after researching, it appeard that fromHeader (the extractor) is not well functionning in passport-jwt@4.0.0 so I used fromAuthHeaderWithScheme instead . Like this :

```
jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('JWT'),
```

and now it is working just fine .